# Best way to allow c# clients to connect to SQL without hardcoding connection string in client

Tags: c#, mysql

Working on a little concept and curious if there is a less clunky way,

Currently I've got both a Client and Server side application. The server side has access to the MySQL locally only.

The clients will send a command via a tcplistener to the server client this will then return the data required

ie:

Client: gettheinfo(username,pass)

Server: gets the info where username,pass is true and return a true to the client to allow login.

Is there a cleaner way to do this without hardcoding the connection string into the client and openning the MySQL port to the public

Comment: You've not really explained your issue very well. Are you saying that the clients are indirectly making SQL queries (as in the client sends the query text and parameters)?

Comment: My apologies,

So the client will send a string to the server such as

'1,user123,pass123'

The server side will then split this into a switch (1) This will then get take user123 & pass123 to perform the SQL query. If this returns true the server will send back y,true or n,false. 

The parsing in then done in reverse and true/false is set to allow login if credentials match

Comment: OK, but why do you need a connection string on the client or to open the MySQL port?

Comment: Im curious if there is a cleaner way than having the client connect to the server via tcplistener and both side then parsing the infomation between each each other. without just letting the client connect directly to the SQL

Comment: Generally you would write an API that's the gatekeeper to the data, and decides who can access what, etc. The client connecting directly to the database is not a clean way of doing something in most scenarios (unless each client user has their very own database and they only get access to that). If the database is shared, then it's a massive security vulnerability that would allow a nefarious user to access everything by simply getting ahold of the connection string.

Comment: An API might not be a bad idea! just thought it might be a bit overkill for just a login system. Thank for a insight into a possible solution :)

Comment: Login systems by themselves don't tend to exist. Usually there are *resources* that must be protected from unauthorized access. Where are those resources in your system? If they're on the client's machine and the only thing protecting access to them is a remote server answering "yes" or "no", you should realise that there's a possibility that that whole remote call could be replaced by a function that just returns "yes" and never calls the server.

Comment: Adding to what Damien said: it could even be done without having to decompile and recompile the code, if someone were interested enough to bypass login.

Comment: As a side note: why send comma-separated values? In a query string you can send `https://yourApiSite.com/login?username=user&passwordHash=0x123456` and the server can easily get hold of these two values using normal query string helpers. Note also the use of a hashed password rather than plain-text